# How to compress an encrypted partition or drive in Windows?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, encryption, compression

Could someone let me know is there any effective way to compress an encrypted drive or partition in Windows to reduce its size ?

Thanks

Comment: Properly encrypted data is not compressible. And what do you mean by "compress an encrypted drive or partition"?

Comment: In general this is a bad idea. in the best cases it would not cause any particular data leakage, but could in other cases reveal information about the plaintext underlying the ciphertext you are attempting to compress. In the absolute worse case, it could concievably return small amounts of cipher code to their unciphered state.

Comment: You can't "compress" a drive or partition anyway, they are fixed size. You can activate compression or encryption on NTFS, but ultimately data has to be compressed before encryption not the other way round

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compression techniques won't work on encrypted files. Nor can you compress a drive or partition directly.

Compress files before encrypting.